# Unhandled Rejection (Error): ENS is not supported on network private

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3-providers, ens

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): ENS is not supported on network private
l.<anonymous>
/packages/web3-eth-ens/lib/ENS.js:481
  478 | if (!this._detectedAddress) {
  479 |     var networkType = await this.eth.net.getNetworkType();
  480 |     var addr = config.addresses[networkType];
> 481 |     if (typeof addr === 'undefined') {
      | ^  482 |         throw new Error("ENS is not supported on network " + networkType);
  483 |     }
  484 |     this._detectedAddress = addr;
View compiled
```

getting this issue in this node module /packages/web3-eth-ens/lib/ENS.js:481
getting this issue for Dapp suddently and i dose able to got the cause why this isuue is occurung, so how can i resolve this issue

Comment: The question needs more details about the development setup, recent changes made, and network configuration to understand and solve the problem effectively. Clarifying specifics about the ENS contract deployment and how to reproduce the error would also help in providing tailored assistance.